# django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“2022-05-19 00:00:00.000” value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.']

Tags: django, flutter, rest, django-rest-framework

i'm trying to make a new object with flutter  and django rest framework ,
the object has a datefield but when i try to make post request and send data from flutter front end to django api i got this error :

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“2022-05-19 00:00:00.000” value has an invalid date 
format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.']
[17/May/2022 22:18:23] "POST /api/reservations/create/ HTTP/1.1" 500 181841
```

this is the post method :

```
       void creerReservations() async {
        _setIds();
      
      client.post(Uri.parse("http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/reservations/create/") , body: {
          "date" : dateRendezvous.toString(),
          "startTime" :startTime.toString(),
          "endTime" :endTime.toString() , 
          "description" :  ' no description for now',
          "patient" : _patient_id.toString(),
          "docteur" : _docteur_id.toString() , 
          "disponible" : "True"
      });
}
```

Django class :

```
 # Create your models here.

class Reservation(models.Model):
date = models.DateField()
startTime =  models.TimeField()
endTime =  models.TimeField()
description = models.TextField()
patient = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE ,  related_name="patient")
docteur = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE , related_name="docteur")
disponible =  models.BooleanField( default= True )

def __str__(self):
    return self.date
```

serializer :

```
class ReservationSerializer(ModelSerializer):
  class Meta : 
    model = Reservation
    fields = '__all__'
```

the variable types :

```
 DateTime dateRendezvous = DateTime.now();
 TimeOfDay startTime = TimeOfDay(hour: 15, minute: 0);
 TimeOfDay endTime = TimeOfDay(hour: 15, minute: 0);
 int _patient_id = 0;
 int _docteur_id = 0;
 bool? disponible;
```

i tried this solution and it worked for me , but it is not technical :
dateRendezvous.toString().substring(0,9),
i took the first 10 character of “2022-05-19 00:00:00.000” and it works fine .

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I misread the Q.  Your issue is "*how do I send a date string using flutter*", and has nothing to do with  DRF but I'm leaving this  up in case it helps.

---

You need to use a [`DateTimeField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield) if you want both components.  [`DateField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#datefield) is for dates only, and will raise the error you see if you ass in the time as well.

DRF will map the django fields to the expected serializer field types automatically based on the model fields.

If you want the `yyyy-mm-dd` part only only, then don't send the `00:00:00` time component in your request.

Read the [DRF documentation on date time fields](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#date-and-time-fields) as well.  You are going to need to pass that with a `T` between the date and the time, [iso-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) style, or you can manually specify input formats according to the documentation.